# HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type error

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, http, http-status-code-415

The origin server is refusing to service the request because the payload is in a format not supported by this method on the target resource.

Controller code

```
@RestController
public class UserController
{
    @Autowired
    public IretrieveService retrieveService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ModelAndView doRegister(@RequestBody UserBean userBean,BindingResult result)
    {
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("index");
        System.out.println("username "+userBean.getUsername());
        if(!result.hasFieldErrors())
        {
            if(retrieveService.insert(userBean) != null)
            {
                System.out.println("done");
            }

        }   
        return view;

    }
}
```

Angular js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller("UserController", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http, httpPostService) {
 var self=this;
 self.userBean={username:''};
$scope.insertData = function()
{
    alert($scope.userBean.username);
     $http({
         method: "POST",
         url: "register",
         data: $scope.userBean.username
        }).then(function(response){
         console.log(response.status);
         console.log("in success");

     }, function(response){
         console.log(response.status);
         console.log("in fail");     
     });
};
}]);
</script>


<form method="post" action="register" name="myForm">
      <label for="username" class="control-label">First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" data-ng-model="userBean.username" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Firstname"/>
       <button type="submit" data-ng-click="insertData()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Error comes but didn't pass value from angular js to controller class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the data you send to the controller is a String and not a UserBean object. Your payload is `$scope.userBean.username` but your controller expects `@RequestBody UserBean userBean`.

Changing the controller to

```
    public ModelAndView doRegister(@RequestBody String userName, BindingResult result)
```

might solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting 415 http error because of your controller expects application/json but you are sending raw string data.

Here is a working example of how to post json data:

Javascript:

```
var data = { "name":"emre" }
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/yourUrl",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json",
    cache: false,
    timeout: 600000,
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success")
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert("ERROR : ", e);
    }
});
```

Controller :

```
@CrossOrigin
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity post(@RequestBody UserBean request) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(request); // your response

}
```

UserBean class :

```
@Data // comes from lombok for getter setter purpose
class UserBean {
    private String name;
}
```

You can adjust controller and javascript according to your needs.